# SQL Joining on 5 Tables - Inclusion & Exclusion

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, union

I want to join 5 tables to come up with 3 different result sets.

My tables are:

1. Customers - contains email address (unique id), email address domain name, account name, demographic info, etc (Customers)
2. Product 1 customer account names (Product1Accounts)
3. Product 1 customer email address domain names (Product1Domains)
4. Product 2 customer account names (Product2Accounts)
5. Product 2 customer email address domain names (Product2Domains)

The 3 results I need are:

1. Product 1 customers excluding Product 2 customers
2. Product 2 customers excluding Product 1 customers
3. Customers of both Product 1 and 2

Side Note: a customer of each product could be identified by account OR domain name.

I can create the following to come up with matches on table 1,2,3 or 1,4,5 but I am getting hung up on how to incorporate the exclusions

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers
INNER JOIN Product1Accounts 
ON Customers.Company=Product1Accounts.Account
UNION
SELECT *
FROM Customers
INNER JOIN Product1Domains 
on Customers.Email_Address_Domain=Product1Domains.Domain
```

I'm also not sure how to obtain the 3rd result set I am looking for... any help or advice on how to write this code better would be appreciated.

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: SQL Server Express 2017 / SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the third result you can just keep adding `UNION`s to get the additional results for the `Product2` tables (which really smells like the database needs to be normalized).

For the first two results the `EXCEPT` keyword should work. I don't work with SQL Express, so I'm not sure if it's available in that version of SQL Server, but check it out. Your code would look like:

```
(
SELECT C.Company
FROM Customers C
INNER JOIN Product1Accounts PA ON PA.Account = C.Company
UNION
SELECT C.Company
FROM Customers C
INNER JOIN Product1Domains PD ON PD.Domain = C.Email_Address_Domain
)
EXCEPT
(
SELECT C.Company
FROM Customers C
INNER JOIN Product2Accounts PA ON PA.Account = C.Company
UNION
SELECT C.Company
FROM Customers C
INNER JOIN Product2Domains PD ON PD.Domain = C.Email_Address_Domain
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your database structure is not correct, you are having 2 different tables for the 2 products. Does it mean that if in future you have 5 more products, you will have 5 more tables?

I think its better to remove the **product1** and **product2** tables and create one product table, then you can have another table that can be called productType which have the information about the type of the product and with a Foreign Key its connected to your main **product Table**

Also does any of your product tables have a Foreign Key available in your customers table? from what I can see they name of the columns you are trying to do the join on are not really clear to be a foreign key.

Comment: Yes, I agree - it is a very messy structure at the moment. Unfortunately all I have to match on now is the company and domain names.